# Отправка данных на сервер node.js и их обработка

Tags: javascript, node.js, сервер, express

Хочу задать вопрос по серверу на `node.js`, а именно отправка файлов на него и обработка. По одному обучающему видео мы просто создавали сервер, а уже от другого автора я смотрел как принимать данные и запутался и может что-то не так сделал. В общем вот мой код сервера:

```
const http = require('http');

//Обработчик формы
const app = require('express')(),
      bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use('/place', bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false,
}));

app.post('/place', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body);
});

app.listen(4000);

const public = require('./resources/js/public');
const home = require('./resources/js/home');
const notFound = require('./resources/js/notFound');

http.createServer((req, res) => {
  if (req.url.match(/\.(html|css|js|png)$/)) {
    public(req, res);
  } else if (req.url === '/') {
    home(req, res);
  } else {
    notFound(req, res);
  }
}).listen(3000, () => console.log('server working'))
```

Я хотел бы спросить, нужно ли нам создавать какой-то файл как указание на него путь в `action` и на сервере в `use post`? в моем случае `/place`. Какого он должен быть формата?
Что значит `app.listen`? и может я допустил ошибку что создал `listen` и тут и ниже на:

```
http.createServer((req, res) => {
  if (req.url.match(/\.(html|css|js|png)$/)) {
    public(req, res);
  } else if (req.url === '/') {
    home(req, res);
  } else {
    notFound(req, res);
  }
}).listen(3000, () => console.log('server working'))
```

Comment: это вы по какому учебнику учите?

Comment: просто видео в интернете просто первое было без отправки на сервер

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen_path_callback

Answer (score 0):

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use('/resources', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname + '/resources')));

app.post('/place', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body);
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on: ${port}`));
```

Answer (score 0):

как я понял ты поднимаешь в этом фале 2 слушателя: порт 4000 для api и 3000 для статики (фронта). Так лучше не делать, а роутинг для фронтенда реализовывать средствами самого фронтенда.
Если всё-таки необходимо продолжить в таком формате, то можно использовать

```
res.static(path.resolve(__dirname + '/resources'))
```